# Modify a specific line in a text file

Tags: c#

is someone knows how I may replace a line in a txt file? 
For exemple i have 10 lines in the file and I want to replace the line[4]. 
I actually have this code:

```
string old = "old string";
string nw =" new string";
int counter = 0;

foreach(string s in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    if (s = old) 
    {
        //replace the line[counter] of the text file 
    } 
    counter ++;
}
```

---

I know I can make a StringCollection and add each lines in the StringCollection indexes and replace only the index that contains the string to replace and overwrite the text file but it may sometimes needs a lot of resources.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: As a side note, your line of code should say `if (s == old)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the whole file again would be easier:

```
string old = "old string";
string nw =" new string";
int counter = 0;

    Using(StreamWriter w =new StreamWriter("newfile");
    foreach(string s in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (s = old) 
        {
              w. WriteLine(nw);
        }
        else
        {
              w. WriteLine(s);
        } 
        counter ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `StreamWriter`, passing in a `FileStream` to it's constructor. You should be able to set the position of the `FileStream` to the point you want to insert you new line

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, could be the following:

Define a few extension methods:

```
static class Exts
{
public static string GetLettersAndDigits(this string source)
{
    return source.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit)
        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, x) => acc.Append(x))
        .ToString();
}

public static string ReplaceWord(this string source, string word, string newWord)
{
    return String.Join(" ", source
        .Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var w = x.GetLettersAndDigits();
            return w == word ? x.Replace(w, newWord) : x;
        }));
}
}
```

**Usage Example:**

```
var input = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");
var output = input.ReplaceWord(s, "123"); // do this inside your foreach
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the entire thing in line by line you could take advantage of string.Replace. Just read the entire file in and replace the old with the new:

```
        using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var textReplaced = text.Replace(old, nw);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if it's a big file? Why read in the whole thing just to write out one different line?

Comment: Yes definitely don't do this for big files.