# Recording frequencies in a list

Tags: c#, listbox, frequency

Hi all I'm having trouble writing a program that will record the frequency of  how often a random number appears.

I'm using visual studio 2017 and c#

I have a file that contains the frequency

```
434
343
454
454
```

& then I've displayed the file in a list box like this

```
1    434
2    343
3    454
4    454
```

now I'm stuck on how to change data from the file so that the corresponding line increments by 1 when a number appears

Is their a function inside c# to allow one to go to a specific line in a text file then increase it's value by one or maybe go to a specific line in the listbox.

e.g. if 3 appears I want to go to line 3 and increase the number by 1.

I don't necessarily want anyone to write out the code for me, I would just love a pointer in the right direction

Comment: As long as I know you have to rewrite the whole file. Have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971008/edit-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971008/edit-a-specific-line-of-a-text-file-in-c-sharp) or [Modify a specific line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003630/modify-a-specific-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Create a keyvaluepair or a dictionary, store pairs like number-amount_of_appearances. When you find a number in a file, just increment it like structure[number]+=1; After parsing the whole file, generate a new one.

Comment: only modify a text file when you are finished with your work in memory, i.e prefer to rewrite entire file only once

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the original file, write out a new one with the frequencies.  Then, when you are done, if you need it to replace the original, copy over it.

It's incredibly hard to edit a given file in place, especially if you need to change the position of other data.